# Is mongoDB suitable for a blogging platform like blogger?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

Im going to try to develop a web application like blogger(blogspot). I'm going to have users, every user will have a blog, the user can post in his blog, the post will have tags. Other users should be able to search by tags or text. Blogs will have settings and theming.

Is it good to use mongodb or would you suggest me another database?

Comment: First you have to decide what "suitable" means to you.

Comment: This could help you get started: http://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb+blog+tutorial

Comment: My blog runs with mongodb, and so far i had no problems. MongoDB has a nice scalability which fits perfect in your project. A common setup is to keep the userdata in a RDBMS and the other stuff like blogposts, tags, categories in an nosql database.

Comment: I'm going to make an application that MAKES blogs (if that makes a differnece). By "suitable" I mean is it ok to use many-to-many, one-to-many, fulltext search & etc.

Comment: As a complete aside, it would be just "&c.", since the ampersand is actually a stylized "et".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am personally developing similar software as a hobby and chose MongoDB as the main database, so I will talk in the light of this experience.

The few reasons that decided me to use MongoDB:

- good scalability
- possibility to save binary files in the DB effectively via GridFS
- flexible schema design by using embedded documents (eg, for comments on posts)
- easy way to look for values in array that can be useful for tag like functionality
- bson format that is easy to manipulate program side

The thing you might want to think well is the schema design, as some bad choices can impact performance on the long run. Specially regarding the use of embedded documents or references.
Trees can also be somehow tricky to implement, but nothing very complicated.

A few ressources you might find valuable:

- [Schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)
- [Full text search](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo)
- [Trees](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB)
- [Application development](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/)
- [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/gridfs/)

And if you want to a nice introduction to MongoDB, I really recommend the reading of "MongoDB In Action" by Kyle Banker.

Update:

As Akshat Jiwan Sharma pointed, the [Little MongoDB Book](http://openmymind.net/2011/3/28/The-Little-MongoDB-Book/) is a very good free resource.

Comment: +1 good answer.I would just like to add The little mongoDb book is quite good too and its free!

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I updated the post with the link to it.

Comment: Piggybacking on the mongoDb book is this interactive shell which walks you through doing anykind of creation with mongo: http://mongly.com/ specifically http://tutorial.mongly.com/tutorial/index

Answer (score 1):

While a blogging system is a good use for mongoDb there were certain problems that I faced while evaluating its usability.

1)Host providers :- MongoDb has only two well known hosting providers (mongoLab and mongoHq) both of them charge heavily.And for shared hosting platforms like Godady mongoDb does not work.So you are left with two choices

a)Use one of the two providers.

b)Use a VPS which is again very expensive(or a cloud hosting system like amazon which is free for the first year).

2)You need to figure out a server for your application too which will increase the cost of hosting.

So for blogging applications I would not recommend mongoDb unless you have the money to spend on hosting.

As an alternative check out couchDb it offers two major advantages.

1)Free to cheap hosting by iris couch.

2)Couch apps, which basically cut out the middle application layer and allow you to host your applications from within the database itself.

You can easily integrate fulltext search for couch db using many of the availaible plugins of lucene and solr. Personally I am leaning towards elastic search since it seems very easy to implement.

It is not too hard to learn couch db and it is very easy to build couchApps which are perfect for blogging in my opinion.

Hope this helps.